# Does sticking to one exercise for a long time cause a plateau, where the body no longer makes improvements even after muscular failure?

Tags: exercise, muscle-endurance, tendons, plateau, strength-gain

**Question** 
Does sticking to a single exercise cause a plateau, and by "plateau"

I mean: "a point in your training where neither reaching failure nor trying to push beyond failure on a specific exercise results in any measurable improvements in strength or endurance"

**The Origin of my Question** 
I have been bicep curling dumbbells of 17.5kg for a month now, reaching failure in three sets and then failure in a fourth eccentric set.

But in all this time, I have not made any improvements. My plan was that once I reached a point where I could do ten reps, I would then increase the weight. But it never happened. I always reach failure on the sixth rep, I think even if a gun was put to my head and I was told to curl the seventh, I would not be able to do it.

(Additional information:

- Diet is fine
- Sleep is fine)

in my infinite wisdom i took to youtube to answer my question. Some strength athletes have had the same experience. This issue of plateaus is the basis for Todd Hutchings, (a popular Arm Wrestler) changing his max effort exercise every week.

But I am also interested in what any scientific research has found regarding plateaus.
Do they exist, as I described them?

> a point in your training where neither reaching failure nor trying to push beyond failure on a specific exercise results in any measurable improvements in strength or endurance

Comment: I'm confused, you say you are reaching failure on the sixth rep of the third set so how does the quoted notion apply?

Comment: in my specific case, (which is not the principle issue here btw. I am mainly concerned with a general answer to my question)what i mean is the number of reps I can do does not increase beyond six. i reach failure after the sixth rep. Based on what is known about failure, one would think I should make strength/endurance gains because I reached failure, but nope i made zero improvements for an entire month of consistently reaching failure and that is why i am asking if such a plateau is normal

Comment: It's very unusual for someone to reach failure with either arm, and after the same number of reps first set and last. Normally people have a stronger arm, and are able to do several more reps the first set than they are able to do for the last set. I suggest you get more rest (more days off) than normal and do a single set of more than six reps. Do it at the beginning of your workout. Prove to yourself you can do it.